# Div to follow scrollbar proportionally on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scrollbar, sticky

I'm now struggling on a sticky element that should scroll proportionally on a page. From top to the footer despite the page's height. So it's actually stick to the top of the scrollbar in the beginning and then to the bottom at the end. Or it just follows the scroll wheel.

Is there any chance to do it with jQuery ?

Below is the starting code with usual "sticky" div.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
$("#sticky")
.animate({"marginTop":($(window).scrollTop())+"px"}, "fast");});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/flakessp/cxr78xc8/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    // calculate the percentage the user has scrolled down the page
    var scrollPercent = 100 * $(window).scrollTop() / ($(document).height() - $(window).height());

    // get the height of the sticky element
    var stickyHeight = $('.sticky').height();

    // calculate the margin top of the sticky element
    var marginTop = (($(window).height() - stickyHeight) / 100) * scrollPercent;

    // set margin top of sticky element
    $('.sticky').css('marginTop', marginTop);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pn6bum9t/1/)

Answer (score 0):

So, this one was a little tricky, but here it is:

## [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/cxr78xc8/1/)

Basically, we're using a couple things here:

Scroll direction detection with this section:

```
var lastScrollPos = 0,
 ...
lastScrollPos < $window.scrollTop()
```

Then, you forgot to factor in things like document and window height. `scrollTop` does exactly what it says and only gives you the number from the top of the viewport to the top of the document.  So we add in the visible height as well with `$(window).height()`.

Then it's just a matter of whether we factor in the height of the element too (hence the ternary operator adding `0` or `$('#sticky').height()` depending on our scroll direction detection from the earlier section.

Anyhow, here's the full JS:

```
var lastScrollPos = 0,
    $window = $(window),
    $document = $(document),
    $sticky = $('#sticky');
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $sticky
    .animate({"top":((($window.scrollTop() + (lastScrollPos < $window.scrollTop() ? $window.height() - $sticky.height() : 0))/$document.height()) * 100)+"%"}, "fast");    
});
```